# how to import a .dmp file in oracle sql developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

How can i import a .dmp file in to sql developer. i had already created schema and i just need to insert data with these dump files. I tried imp and impdb commmands in sql command line but of no use.

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/sqldev/r31/datapump_OBE/datapump.html?

Comment: im unable to access that dump file..is there any other option???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use SQL Developer to process data pump or legacy EXPORT dumps.

You CAN use SQL Developer to create a Data Pump job which will process your data pump export - this assumes the file is avail on a DB directory.

For a better answer, tell us exactly what kind of 'dmp' file you have.

If it's a Oracle Export dmp, the only way to import it is with the Import utility.